# write string to pointer C++

Tags: c++, dll, code-injection

I have a Dll which I inject into my target process.
This Dll changes some variables at give memory addresses.
Normaly I do it like:

```
  int* variable = (int*)0x????????;
  *variable = 1;
```

Now I want to do the same thing with a string.
Reading the string works.

```
string* variable = (string*) 0x????????;
```

But changing the string crashes the process.

```
*variable = "hello world"; //crash
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is extremely dodgy. You can sort of hack it for simple, built-in types, but a `std::string` is no such thing. It contains pointers to data and you're not handling that. What on earth are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: change the string stored at the address.

Comment: Where do you get that address from? Why do you think there is properly constructed object at that address?

Comment: I read it before to check.

Comment: No, that's _how_ you're trying to accomplish it. _What_ are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: _"I read it before to check"_ That is not a valid check. Where did the address come from?

Comment: It displays the right string if I use `sprintf();` I try to hack a game (change player name)

Comment: You have a null terminated C string there, don't you?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean... I'm a C# boy.

Comment: I mean you have to basically use poor C, no C++ objects for such hacks. `std::string` is an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `std::string` or any other non [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) data type this way. What you need to do instead:

```
 char* variable = (char*) 0x????????;
 strcpy( variable, "hello world" );
```

or other, maybe MS specific functions to manipulate C strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown how you guarantee that the memory at the address `0x????????` is allocated properly or that the string object is initialized.

If the pointer does not point to allocated memory, or if the string is not initialized when you copy-assign it, then you get undefined behaviour. Possible undefined behaviour include:

> But changing the string crashes the process.

To fix it, allocate and initialize a string object and use the address of that string.

Comment: some source I could leech?